# How do I redirect stdout & error to 2 separate files?

Tags: bash, shell

I know how to redirect stdout & stderr to one file:

```
my_command_to_start_server &> app.log
```

but how can I redirect the stdout & stderror to 2 files?

In essence I want to duplicate what's getting written to my app.log to my health.log

Comment: Do you mean you want stdout to go to one file and stderr to a different file? Or do you mean you want both stdout and stderr to go to both `fileA` and also`fileB`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell - I want both stdout and stderr to be written to `fileA` and `fileB`

Answer (score 1):

Use `tee`.

```
my_command_to_start_server 2>&1 | tee app.log health.log > /dev/null
```

`2>&1` makes standard error whatever standard output already is, effectively "merging" them.  (`&> ...` is a shortcut for `> ... 2> ...`, which doesn't allow for the use of a pipe.) Then you pipe the merged stream to `tee`, which writes its standard input to both named files.

`tee` also writes to its own standard output, which we redirect to `/dev/null` instead of picking an arbitrary file to redirect standard output to with something like

```
... | tee health.log > app.log
```